# Неопределенное поведение функции strlen (неправильно считает)

Tags: c++, строки, кодировка, strlen

Пытаюсь создать собственный строковый класс. Оказалось, функция strlen как-то не так работает, как ожидалось. Что я делаю не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class my_str {
    private:
        char* s;
    public:
        my_str();
        my_str(const char *str);
        my_str(const my_str &ob);
        ~my_str();
        my_str &operator=(const my_str &ob);
        void my_strlen();
        void print_str();
};

my_str::my_str()
{
    s = new char [1];
    strcpy (s, "");
    cout << "конструктор" << endl;
}

my_str::my_str(const char *str)
{
    cout << "конструктор парметризованный1" << endl;
    s = new char [strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy (s, str);
    cout << strlen(s);
    cout << "конструктор парметризованный2" << endl;
}

my_str::my_str(const my_str &ob)
{
    s = new char [strlen(ob.s)+1];
    strcpy (s, ob.s);
    cout << "конструктор копии" << endl;
}

my_str::~my_str()
{
    if(s)
        delete [] s;
    cout << "деструктор" << endl;
}

my_str &my_str::operator=(const my_str &ob)
{
    cout << "=" << endl;
    cout << ob.s << endl;
    cout << strlen(ob.s) << endl;
    delete [] s;
    s = new char[strlen(ob.s)+1];
    strcpy(s, ob.s);
    return *this;
}

void my_str::my_strlen()
{
    cout << strlen(s) << endl;
}

 void my_str::print_str()
{
    if(s) {
        for(int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
            cout << s[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "_" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    my_str a("Привет "), b("всем!"), c;
    cout <<strlen("Привет ")<< endl;
    a.my_strlen();
    cout <<strlen("всем!")<<endl;
    b.my_strlen();
    c.my_strlen();
    c=a;
    c.my_strlen();
    c.print_str();
    a=b;
    a.my_strlen();
    a.print_str();
    return 0;
}
```

После запуска программы получаю (компилятор g++):

```
конструктор парметризованный1
13конструктор парметризованный2
конструктор парметризованный1
9конструктор парметризованный2
конструктор
13
13
9
9
0
=
Привет
13
13
▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒   _
=
всем!
9
9
▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ! _
деструктор
деструктор
деструктор
```

Почему 13 и 9, когда должно быть 7 и 5??  И вот эти странные символы откуда берутся, когда выводишь посимвольно, а не строкой?

Была заменена кодировка сначала на ASCII, затем на Windows-1251. strlen стала верно считать. Однако с русскими буквами стало ещё хуже:

```
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ 1
7▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ 2
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ 1
5▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ 2
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
7
7
5
5
0
=
▒▒▒▒▒▒
7
7
▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ▒   _
=
▒▒▒▒!
5
5
▒ ▒ ▒ ▒ ! _
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

Теперь всё в иероглифах. Вернуться к предыдущим кодировкам уже не получается...

Comment: Думаю, что у вас исходник в UTF-8, и на русские буквы приходится больше одного байта... Вот из 7 символов - 6 русских + ASCII получается 6*2+1=13, из 4+1 - 9...

Comment: `Привет ` в UTF-8:  D0 9F D1 80 D0 B8 D0 B2 D0 B5 D1 82 20, а какая у вас ОС и что за редактор? в винде в VS это надо набирать: u8"Привет "

Comment: Код пишу в Notepad++ (да, кодировка UTF-8). Запускаю программу через MINGW64 (Git Bash). ОС - Windows 7.

Comment: В Notepad++ u8 нет. Предлагает в ASCII преобразовать, попробую.

Comment: Для начала поставьте эксперимент: используйте только символы из младшей половины ASCII: пробел, цифры, знаки препинания, английские большие и маленькие буквы. Скорее всего, функция будет работать правильно. Это значит, кодировка редактора отличается от однобуквенной. Ставьте кодировку CP1251. В командной строке выполните `chcp 1251`, тогда вывод вашей программы будет корректным.

Comment: Вопрос решился весьма странным образом. Сначала в файле была изменена кодировка на ASCII ( не помогло), потом на Кириллицу Windows-1251 (не помогла). Пришлось заменить все слова на латиницу, тогда стало возможно доработать прогу. Позже текст был скопирован и вставлен в новый файл, где по умолчанию UTF-8. В нём же латиница заменена русским алфавитом. Всё заработало!! Так и осталось не ясным, как именно это произошло?..